IntelliJ SQL-Formatter to indent SET after UPDATE
How can I modify the IntelliJ SQL-Formatter to insert an indent before the SET (after an UPDATE)?
Current code:
UPDATE role
SET is_available = 0
  , is_updated = 1
    WHERE name = 'Admin';

Desired code formatting with indent for SET:
UPDATE role
    SET is_available = 0
      , is_updated = 1
    WHERE name = 'Admin';

My current IntelliJ configuration (codeStyles/Project.xml) is:
    <component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
      <code_scheme name="Project" version="173">
        <option name="LINE_SEPARATOR" value="&#10;" />
        <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="120" />
        <option name="SOFT_MARGINS" value="80,100,120" />
        <SqlCodeStyleSettings version="7">
          <option name="KEYWORD_CASE" value="2" />
          <option name="IDENTIFIER_CASE" value="1" />
          <option name="TYPE_CASE" value="4" />
          <option name="CUSTOM_TYPE_CASE" value="1" />
          <option name="ALIAS_CASE" value="4" />
          <option name="BUILT_IN_CASE" value="4" />
          <option name="QUOTED_IDENTIFIER_CASE" value="1" />
          <option name="QUOTE_TYPE" value="20" />
          <option name="QUERY_SECTION_1ST_WORD_ALIGN" value="2" />
          <option name="QUERY_EL_COMMA" value="1" />
          <option name="SUBQUERY_OPENING" value="1" />
          <option name="SUBQUERY_CONTENT" value="1" />
          <option name="SUBQUERY_CLOSING" value="3" />
          <option name="SUBQUERY_PAR_SPACE_BEFORE" value="1" />
          <option name="INSERT_INTO_NL" value="2" />
          <option name="INSERT_CONTENT" value="0" />
          <option name="INSERT_TABLE_EL_LINE" value="1" />
          <option name="INSERT_VALUES_EL_LINE" value="1" />
          <option name="INSERT_EL_WRAP" value="0" />
          <option name="INSERT_MATRIX_INCLUDING_HEADER" value="true" />
          <option name="SET_ALIGN_EQUAL_SIGN" value="false" />
          <option name="WITH_EL_WRAP" value="2" />
          <option name="WITH_ALIGN_AS" value="true" />
          <option name="SELECT_EL_WRAP" value="3" />
          <option name="SELECT_KEEP_N_ITEMS_IN_LINE" value="3" />
          <option name="SELECT_USE_AS_WORD" value="1" />
          <option name="FROM_EL_COMMA" value="0" />
          <option name="FROM_ALIGN_JOIN_TABLES" value="true" />
          <option name="FROM_INDENT_JOIN" value="false" />
          <option name="FROM_ONLY_JOIN_INDENT" value="2" />
          <option name="FROM_PLACE_ON" value="21" />
          <option name="WHERE_EL_LINE" value="1" />
          <option name="ORDER_EL_WRAP" value="2" />
          <option name="TABLE_OPENING" value="1" />
          <option name="TABLE_CONTENT" value="2" />
          <option name="TABLE_CLOSING" value="3" />
          <option name="TABLE_ALTER_ITEM_WRAP" value="2" />
          <option name="CONSTRAINT_WRAP_2" value="true" />
          <option name="CONSTRAINT_WRAP_4" value="true" />
          <option name="CREATE_SCHEMA_CONTENT_INDENT" value="false" />
          <option name="VIEW_INDENT_QUERY" value="true" />
          <option name="ROUTINE_ARG_CONTENT" value="2" />
          <option name="ROUTINE_ARG_CLOSING" value="3" />
          <option name="ROUTINE_ARG_WRAP" value="2" />
          <option name="ROUTINE_ARG_COMMA" value="1" />
          <option name="SCRIPT_STMT_SEMICOLON_WRAP" value="2" />
          <option name="IMP_COMMON_WRAP_EVERY_STATEMENT" value="true" />
          <option name="IMP_DECLARE_EL_WRAP" value="1" />
          <option name="IMP_DECLARE_ALIGN_DEFAULT" value="true" />
          <option name="IMP_IF_THEN_WRAP_THEN" value="true" />
          <option name="IMP_IF_THEN_INDENT_THEN_ELSE" value="true" />
          <option name="EXPR_SPACE_WITHIN_PARENTHESES" value="true" />
          <option name="EXPR_CASE_THEN_WRAP" value="true" />
          <option name="EXPR_CASE_THEN_ALIGN" value="true" />
          <option name="EXPR_CASE_END" value="1" />
          <option name="EXPR_CASE_KEEP_NL_AFTER_THEN" value="true" />
          <option name="INDEX_NAME_TEMPLATE" value="{unique?u:}k_{table}_{columns}" />
          <option name="PRIMARY_KEY_NAME_TEMPLATE" value="pk_{table}" />
          <option name="FOREIGN_KEY_NAME_TEMPLATE" value="fk_{table}_{ref_table}_{ref_columns}" />
        </SqlCodeStyleSettings>
        <codeStyleSettings language="SQL">
          <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
          <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
          <indentOptions>
            <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
            <option name="SMART_TABS" value="true" />
          </indentOptions>
        </codeStyleSettings>
      </code_scheme>
    </component>

On the other hand it was no problem to achieve indents for all other code snippets like:
INSERT INTO my_temporary_table (id, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4)
    VALUES (26, 42 + 1, 42 + 2, 12345, 67890)

or
ALTER TABLE t1
    ADD first  char(1)    DEFAULT 'A' NOT NULL,
    ADD second varchar(2) DEFAULT 'B' NOT NULL,
    ADD third  varchar(160)           NULL;

Basically I want to achieve the SET in the UPDATE is intended like the other statements.

Are you certain IntelliJ supports this?

No, I am not. But I configured for example MODIFY (in alter table xy) to have the expected behaviour with the configuration above.
